# how to select county state city in grails dynamically

Tags: grails, gsp

I am trying to fetch `country` ,`state` and `city` from my database using domain classes. But I need any easier way to fetch them. Is there any way to get these by using a Grails tag?

```
<g:countrySelect/>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
    <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: accountInstance, field: 'country', 'error')} ">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label" for="country">
        <g:message code="account.country.label" default="Country" />
        </label>

        <g:select id="country" name="country.id" from="${org.preva.Country.list()}"
                  optionKey="id" value="${accountInstance?.country?.id}"
                  class="many-to-one" noSelection="['null': 'Choose Country']"
                  style="width:160px"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
    <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: accountInstance, field: 'state', 'error')} ">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label" for="state">
        <g:message code="account.state.label" default="State" />
        </label>
        <g:select id="state" name="state.id" from="${org.preva.State.list()}"
                  optionKey="id" value="${accountInstance?.state?.id}"
                  class="many-to-one" noSelection="['null': 'Choose State']"
                  style="width:160px"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
    <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: accountInstance, field: 'city', 'error')} ">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label" for="city">
        <g:message code="account.city.label" default="City" />
        </label>
        <g:select id="city" name="city.id" from="${org.preva.City.list()}"
                  optionKey="id" value="${accountInstance?.city?.id}"
                  class="many-to-one" noSelection="['null': 'Choose City']"
                  style="width:160px"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any default tag?

Comment: you mean you're looking for something easier that current `org.preva.City.list()`? I don't really understand current problem

Comment: like in grails we have  <g:countrySelect name="user.country" value="${country}"
                 noSelection="['':'-Choose your country-']"/> for country selection .so like this  is there any predefined tag for state and city i am asking.

Comment: so the problem that you're using `value="${org.preva.City.list()}"` currently, but want `value="${city}"` instead?

Comment: take a look at ajaxdependancyselection / boselecta plugin